# Asp.net Core SignalR loadbalancer (close connection error)

Tags: asp.net-core, load-balancing, asp.net-core-signalr

We have a signalR structure that clients only listen to, which is triggered from the Admin Panel. Client's connection can stay connected as long as loadbalancer's (Google Cloud Platform) request timeout. After this time, the browser throws a 1006 close connection error and drops off the connection. How can we increase this time(is it good idea to increase to thousands of seconds?) What's the error we're skipping here?

startup.cs

```
services.AddSignalR(HubOptions =>
           {
               HubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
               HubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
               HubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45);

           }).AddJsonProtocol().AddStackExchangeRedis(Configuration.GetSection("RedisConfiguration:Host").Value, options =>
           {               
               options.Configuration.ConfigurationChannel = "dataCache";
               options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "BoardApp";
               options.Configuration.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
           });
```

js.Code

```
 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl("/boardscreenhub", { transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
                    .withAutomaticReconnect([1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, null])
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information).build();

                connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1800000;
                connection.start();

                connection.on("receiveMessage", function (message) {
                    _this4.setBoardScreenData(message);
                });
```

Comment: Please share the detailed error message/log. Besides, [the recommended `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value is double the `KeepAliveInterval` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options), if you try to change it as recommended, does it work well?

Comment: I was updated code. serverTimeoutInMilliseconds:30 minute and KeepAliveInterval:15 minute. But not work. 
Error log: https://imgur.com/lRt9JeZ
How can I get a more detailed error list?

Comment: Does the issue occur on specific browser client?

Comment: No. Every browser has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have session affinity enabled for the backend of your loadbalancer? We have had the same issue, and I believe that if you do not, then the connections will not be stable and so keep-alives will get lost and give you this behavior.